# Socket for Old Edge Connector

Tags: pcb, socket, edge-connector

I have an old PCB with an edge connector and I am looking for a way to create a socket for it. I have a 3D printer so the housing is not an issue but where I am stuck is the contacts.

The edge connector has 25 fingers. Each finger is 3mm wide and 6mm long. The finger spacing is 5mm. The fingers are on both sides of the PCB.

Are suitable pin contacts available separately? I can't seem to find them.

Is there a suitable off-the-shelf edge connector socket where the pins can be removed without damage to them and they are the right size?

I believe on the original socket the pins were 1mm wide.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it not a standard pin spacing, such as 0.1 inch?  Buying a connector, and if necessary sawing it to length, would be easier if you can find one.

Comment: Maybe you can build something out of theese: https://www.samtec.com/products/sir1

Comment: The spacing could be 5.08mm, that is, 0.2" (200 mil.) You might have better luck with with that.

Comment: I am sure you can find something off the shelf. If not here are spring fingers: https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=6-1773460-8_Spring_Fingers&DocType=DS&DocLang=EN

Answer (score 0):

Almost all contacts for connectors (especially small pitched connectors) are developed inside a manufacturer for a specific housing that they develop. Pins and contacts require special machinery to stamp, punch and bend pins out of sheet metal (machining contacts is more expensive).

The easiest thing for you would be to find an existing housing that has similar pitch and scavenge the pins from that connector for your design. Check [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/rectangular-connectors-headers-male-pins/314?s=N4IgjCBcpg7AnABiqAxlAZgQwDYGcBTAGhAHsoBtcMMANgBYQSxEAOdp8RAZjc5dgBWbvwBMg0bH7dY9CMzCTkCmYwVJ4YxPHnhRYesr30EYibTO1RY2oIvNR7XYtZIx8bpubdaH6bFFGAF0SAAcAFygQAGVwgCcASwA7AHMQAF90kmtIKlRSJKSQIPSgA) or mouser for different connectors.

If not then its possible for you to design your own pins (if cost isn't an issue, it will be expensive) and have a machinist machine them for you (and then gold plated which will also be expensive if you need that).

Comment: You could have stamped pins made from phosphor bronze or beryllium copper. I think it would be cheaper than having a machinist make individual pins, even if you only needed 50 or 100.

Answer (score 0):

Is your actual connector pitch is 5.08mm (200 mil)?

If so, you could try the EDAC 243 series modular type, here: https://edac.net/series/243

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - this looks perfect but $15 per piece - wow

Comment: Prices start high because the part is new. Then if it becomes popular sometimes prices drop as multiple vendors compete to create interchangeable parts. Then, it becomes a legacy part, and prices go up again because customers who need to keep legacy HW running are often desparate to do avoid upgrades, and they will pay a lot for those old, nearly obsolete parts. This type of board edge connector is now in the legacy phase.

Comment: If you have a surplus place nearby they might have new old stock of this or something similar.

Comment: @Andy See if the Samtec MEC2 series will work. This is a 2mm pitch. Digi Key & Mouser have stock.